# Showing only the half of an Image on Slick2D?

Tags: java, image, render, slick2d

I'd like to show only the half of an Image in `Slick2D`!
The Problem is: I do NOT want to stretch it in any direction,
so the method

```
image.draw(float x, float y, float srcx, float srcy, float srcx2, float srcy2)
```

doesn't help me.
(That method streches the specified part to the size of the full image and renders then!)

An image crop method may be helpful.

I'd be thankful to get help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you named take the picture, crop it with the `src` parameters but then stretch the cropped part to the original size of the image. That is why you have some problem.

In order to solve this, you must indicate the size of the target area where you want to draw the image. To do so, use the method

[draw(float x, float y, float x2, float y2, float srcx, float srcy, float srcx2, float srcy2)](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#draw%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)

**Source**: last comment on [gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71475/how-can-i-draw-a-part-of-a-texture-in-slick2d)